# cannot use namespace as a type ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am new for ionic app development and this is very basic question i know that but i am facing this issue since one day , I have download one application from internet and when i open code its showing error messages i.e **cannot use namespace as type ionic** ,Why i am getting this error message can some on e help me please

### code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, MenuController, Nav, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { LearnFeedPage } from '../pages/learn-feed/learn-feed';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  // make LearnFeedPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage: any = LearnFeedPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, params: any}>;

  constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public app: App
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: code snippet photo! 1st time I've ever seen one... :)

Comment: sorry for my mistack but i hope you guys understand my problem

Comment: we cant see the code clearly.. Nor can anyone reference it to answer. You will need to provide as text

Comment: have you run "npm install" command?

Comment: yes i run this command in my project

Comment: `LearnFeedPage` are you importing this? not using lazy loading? Also which line does this error refer to?

Comment: StatusBar,splashScreen showing errors like what i ask in question

Comment: hmm.. which typescript version does vscode(?) show in the bottom?

Comment: npm install @ionic-native/splash-screen@latest --save,I have updated latest but still error not going to solve

Comment: i am using 1.24.1 visual studio version

Comment: not vscode, I meant typescript version.. because the code seems fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173743/discussion-between-abhiram-and-suraj-rao).